# Database Report Server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportserver

I'm configuring the Reporting Server, however i have some problems when trying to create a report server database.

I have this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(
       SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(
       SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(
       TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(
       RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, 
       BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(
       String methodName, Boolean async)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(
       DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   em Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.DBUtils.ApplyScript(
       SqlConnection conn, String script, ICommandWrapperFactory commandWrapper)
   em Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.DBUtils.ApplyScript(
       String connectionString, String script)
   em ReportServicesConfigUI.SqlClientTools.SqlTools.ApplyScript(
       String connectionString, String script)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like your user doesn't have the privileges to write in the DB.

Comment: I added the user in Master->Security->Users

Comment: try this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/09/17/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-my-fix.aspx